# How do you enable search for SharePoint site Mailboxes?

Tags: search, site-mailboxes

I have a new site created and added a mailbox but the emails in this new mailbox do not show up when a search from this site is performed. How can this be accomplished.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this can't be performed. Crawling can't handle a site mailbox. Only Exchange Server Public Folder can be crawled with a Search Service Application in SharePoint 2013 Server.

Reference: [Site Mailbox Search](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c7436b38-7eed-4211-85d8-ea1e722bb1ad/site-mailbox-search?forum=sharepointsearch)